# Calling a function with multiple parenthesis

Tags: javascript

While doing some JavaScript challenges, I faced with the code `add(1)(2)`, a function being called with several parenthesis. The challenge is to make a chain of `add` function.

```
add(1)(2)(3);       // -> 6
add(1)(2)(3)(4);    // -> 10
add(1)(2)(3)(4)(5); // -> 15
```

Also, we should be able to store the returned values and reuse them.

```
var addTwo = add(2);

addTwo;       // -> 2
addTwo + 5;   // -> 7
addTwo(3);    // -> 5
addTwo(3)(5); // -> 10
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you share the code in your post please?

Comment: What programming language ?

Comment: I edited the post . It is JavaScript , sorry if  you found my post  little messy it is my first question and i haven't get used to it yet .Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 function sum(firstArg, opt_argsStack) {
    const argsStack = (opt_argsStack || []).concat([firstArg]);

    const nextSum = nextArg => sum(nextArg, argsStack);
    nextSum.valueOf = () => argsStack.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
    return nextSum;
    }

    console.log(+sum(1));
    console.log(+sum(1)(2));
    console.log(+sum(1)(2)(3));
    console.log(+sum(1)(2)(3)(4));
```

Here, we pass the stack of all accumulated arguments down to recursive call. And in valueOf call, stack is transformed to a number via reduce just in time. This gives us more flexibility, imo, if we wanted to change chained sum to chained multiplication or whatever else — we just plug in different reduce function.

refer:https://medium.com/reflecting-on-bits/fun-fact-sum-of-numbers-through-infinite-currying-in-js-a5c229765a18

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Sashi yadav Do not forget to quote the original resource from where you copied the solution. https://medium.com/reflecting-on-bits/fun-fact-sum-of-numbers-through-infinite-currying-in-js-a5c229765a18